# Parsing Apache Log Timestamps with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql, apache, momentjs

I'm attempting to use moment.js to format Apache log timestamps (`14/Jun/2015:11:05:54 -0700`) as proper MySQL `DATETIME` format.

Getting the MySQL `DATETIME` format is a breeze. But moment seems to only auto-detect `ISO 8601` formats. My Node.js console output when passing in the Apache log's timestamp into moment:

```
> moment( '08/Jun/2015:15:03:29' ).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
'Invalid date'
```

I can't figure out a way to parse the Apache log timestamp without doing a ton of string splitting in JavaScript. Is there a clean way of loading the Apache log timestamp into moment? Or perhaps into the `Date` object?

**NOTE:** Changing the Apache log's timestamp format wouldn't work for my case, because I'm working with old log files, not new ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell moment what format the string is in so it can parse it.

Something like:

```
moment( '08/Jun/2015:15:03:29', 'DD/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Ahh, I see. Your answer was dead-on, with the exception of needing to add the offset in there as well.  So format had to be `DD/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z` in the end. Thanks!